# Instances of Iterator, ListIterartor and Enumeration

Tags: java, collections, interface, anonymous-class

There is a piece of code.

```
Vector v = new Vector<>();
Iterator it = v.iterator();
ListIterator lit = v.listIterator();
Enumeration enu=v.elements();
System.out.println(it.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(lit.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(enu.getClass().getName());
```

Here `Iterator`, `ListIterator` and `Enumeration` are interface types
and there are variables holding references of them (`it`, `lit` and `enu`respectively).

When I compiled this code I got anonymous class of `Vector` i.e,

```
java.util.Vector$Itr
java.util.Vector$ListItr
java.util.Vector$1
```

I want to know how did it happen.

Comment: I  recommend you to carefully read [The Java Tutorial, Nested classes chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). This will give you an insight of what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't get anonymous classes of `Vector` in the first two cases (`java.util.Vector$Itr` and `java.util.Vector$ListItr`). `java.util.Vector$something` indicates that `something` is a class nested inside the `java.util.Vector` class. Anonymous classes have no name. `Itr` and 
`ListItr` are class names, so they are definitely not anonymous.

The only case in which you did get an anonymous class instance is in `v.elements()`, since `Vector`'s `elements()` method returns an anonymous class instance that implements the `Enumeration` interface :

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
  return new Enumeration<E>() {
    int count = 0;

    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
      return count < elementCount;
    }

    public E nextElement() {
      synchronized (Vector.this) {
        if (count < elementCount) {
          return (E)elementData[count++];
        }
    }
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: ok fine thanks for the well explain @Eran. can u please tell me about java.util.Vector$something.

Comment: @Roushan45 I only used Vector$something as an example. The actual nested classes are named Vector$Itr and Vector$ListItr

Answer (score 0):

`getClass()` returns the *actual runtime type* of an object rather than the declared type of the variable through which you access the object. This implies that you will *never* see an `interface` type returned by `getClass()`.

Since it is unspecified what actual type the `Vector.iterator()` or `Vector.listIterator()` will return, the result will be arbitrary. In the implementation you have tried, you received classes which seem to be inner classes of `Vector`, which is reasonable, however, if you received top level classes within `java.util` or even classes of an entirely different package, there was nothing wrong with that, as long as these classes implement the contract of the `Iterator`, resp. `ListIterator` interface correctly.

That’s simply implementation specific.